# Change ArgTypes depending on select args

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

Is there a way to dynamically change the `ArgTypes` when `args` of a components changes in Storybook?

For instance, suppose a strory with a component that has 2 controls: `id` and `value`.
`id` can either be `1` or `2`.
If `id == '1'` then `argTypes.value.control.min = 0`, else `argTypes.value.control.min = -100`.

Example code:

```js
export default {
  argTypes: {
    id: { control: { type: 'select', options: ['1', '2']}},
    value: { control: {type: 'range', min:0, max: 100, step:10}},
  }
};

const Template = (args) => <MyComponent {...args} />;

export const Example = Template.bind({});
Template.args = {
  id: '1',
  value: 0,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using two different args and an `if` property.

```
...
argTypes: {
    id: { control: { type: 'select', options: ['1', '2']}},
    valueNatural: {
      control: {type: 'range', min:0, max: 100, step:10},
      if: {arg: 'id', eq: '1'}
    },
    valueInteger: {
      control: {type: 'range', min:-100, max: 100, step:10},
      if: {arg: 'id', eq: '2'}
    }
  }
```